# If $x \leq g(x) \leq x^2-x+1$ where $x \in [0,2]$, can we say that $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $x \leq g(x) \leq x^2-x+1$ where $x \in [0,2]$, can we say that $g(x)$ continuous at $x=1$ ?

Is $g(x)$ continuous in $[0,2]$?

Comment: Yes to the first, not necessarily to the second.

Comment: We can find that $g(1)=1$. Now, apply sandwich lemma.

Comment: @Guillermo , please write out clearly, here $g(1)=1$ , but from that how can you say that g is continuous in 1?

Comment: What have you tried? If you sketch the functions, you will get an idea of what the answer is, and maybe you will get an idea on how to prove it.

Comment: @ROBINSON, consider $x-1\le g(x)-1\le x^2-x+1$. This will help you consider the limit $|g(x)-g(1)|$ in definition of continuity.

Comment: Sketching in matlab?! I think N.U. means for you to draw it on paper. You should also be aware of how to draw examples of continuous and discontinuous functions. Can you do this?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: For the first part, you know that your function can't be "further away" from 1 than either of the bounding functions are. For the second part, you should be able to just draw a counterexample. Start by sketching the two bounding functions.

Answer (score 1):

If $I$ is an intervall and $f,h\colon I\to\mathbb R$ are continuous functions with $f(x)\le h(x)$ for all $x\in I$. Then

- If $f(a)=h(a)$ for some $a\in I$, then any function $g\colon I\to\mathbb R$ with $f(x)\le g(x)\le h(x)$ for all $x\in I$ is continuous at $a$.
- If $f(a)\ne h(a)$, there exists $g\colon I\to \mathbb R$ with $f(x)\le g(x)\le h(x)$ for all $x\in I$ that is not continuous at $a$.

For the first part note that for given $\epsilon>0$ there are $\delta_f,\delta_h>0$ such that for $x\in I$ with $|x-a|<\delta_f$ we have $|f(x)-f(a)|\le \epsilon$ and if $|x-a|<\delta_h$ then $|h(x)-h(a)|<\epsilon$.
Conclude that with $\delta:=\min\{\delta_f,\delta_h\}$ we have $|g(x)-g(a)|\le\epsilon$ if $|x-a|<\delta$.

For the second part, consider $g(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)&\text{if }x\in\mathbb Q,\\h(x)&\text{if }x\notin \mathbb Q.\end{cases} $

Answer (score 1):

For the second one: Assume there is a continues $g(x)$ in $[0,2]$
that satisfy $${x\leq g(x)\leq x^{2}-x+1}$$ note that this
imply $$0.5\leq g(0.5)\leq0.25-0.5+1=0.75$$

Consider $\widehat{g}:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ s.t $\widehat{g}(x)=g(x)$
for all $x\neq0.5$ and such that $$\widehat{g}(0.5)=g(x)+\delta$$
where $\delta\neq0$ is some number such that the above inequality
holds.

Then $\widehat{g}$ satisfy the above inequality but is not continues